# How to remove blank spaces from SQL*Plus query?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

My query below being called from sqlplus is returning lot of spaces in the end of each value, how can I remove it?

See example below:
* I substituted the values with x

```
x            ,x                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                           ,x                             ,x                          ,x,x
x
```

My query is:

```
set linesize 1000
set trimspool on
set trimout on
set pagesize 0
set colsep ,
set feedback off

spool /result.csv

SELECT process_id,
  x1,
  x2,
  x3,
  x4,
  x5,
  x6,
  x
FROM x
WHERE x IN ('x');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to concatenate the columns with the commas in between, rather than using `colsep`:

```
select process_id
    ||','|| x1
    ||','|| x2
...
```

Note that you only have the comma in the concatenation strong, not between the columns. You end up with a single column in the reult.

Comment: it may be the simplest answer, but it also shows the horrible limitations of the tool. The whole purpose of using Sql*Plus is to automate tasks, and a common requirement of automation is to output CSV files. This process makes it really to do your extracts because you have to rewrite your SQL especially for each requirement.