# TRIM char blank trailing spaces for CSV export

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I cant find the answer to this, I have fields in a database I have not got write privileges to that contain a handful of blank spaces due to set sizing. I need to trim that out in the export but TRIM functions aren't working.

I've tried these:

```
TRIM(char(32) from foo)
TRIM(' ' from foo)
LTRIM, RTRIM
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(DELIVERY_NAME)
FROM
    DELIVERY_TABLE
ORDER BY
    DELIVERY_NAME
```

Expected result - `'JOHN WOO'`
Actual result - `'JOHN WOO             '`

Comment: `TRIM` on its own should work fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb97254127d24f8b4b72c97a0b833dc0

Comment: i think because its a char field not a string, it isnt exactly a '    ' and is some sort of special character.

Comment: You've only shown one column here, but from your pastebin example, [are you actually seeing this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17390755/266304)? The problem might just be the use of `colsep`. If you're using SQL Developer (or SQLcl) you can also look at `set sqlformat csv`.

Comment: [More on `sqlformat`.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/) Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077636/266304) for that and other options. (Possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM DELIVERY_NAME)
```

> ```
> select TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM ' Test   ') from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | TRIM(BOTH''FROM'TEST') |
> | :--------------------- |
> | Test                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5a2363772dea5a418576b1eb28826283)*

Alternatively you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(' Test  s ', '^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$','') from dual
```

this removes leading and trailing whitespaces and tabs

Comment: , REGEXP_REPLACE(iso.DELIVERY_NAME, '\s*','') worked sort of, the blank spaces disappeared but the formatting of the table skewed

Comment: additionally it removed spaces in between words not just trailing right hand side

Comment: set colsep ','

SELECT 
    orh.ORDER_NO
    , iso.CUSTOMER_PO_NO
    , iso.CONSIGNMENT_NUMBER
    , REGEXP_REPLACE(iso.DELIVERY_NAME, '^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$','')
    , to_char(orh.DATE_DUE, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
    , iso.DELIVERY_STATE

Comment: that code somehow is now removing the colsep and forcing left and right trailing ',' to break.

Comment: QUERY RESULT looks good, but SCRIPT OUTPUT is what has all the issues when hosting to a CSV

Comment: can I also see part of problematic csv ?